# How to display lightning-checkbox-group with normal, not bold, label?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-checkbox-group

This is what I see:

[image]

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="slds-grid">
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12">
        <lightning-checkbox-group
            name="newusedcheckboxgroup"
            label="Welke artikelen?"
            options={newUsedOptions}
            value={newUsedChoices}
            variant="label-stacked">
        </lightning-checkbox-group>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12">
        <lightning-combobox
            name="artikelzoekoptie"
            label={label.artikelZoekOptie}
            value={searchOption}
            onchange={handleSearchOptionChange}
            options={searchOptions}>
        </lightning-combobox>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

So for some reason, a `lightning-combobox` has a normal label and a `lightning-checkbox-group` has a bold label. I want to use a normal label, how can I do that? I tried applying CSS classes, but that only affected the checkbox option labels, not the top label.

There is also a label-hidden option, but that causes a vertical misalignment with the combobox on the right.

Comment: Have you tried to use Styling Hooks?
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/checkbox/#Styling-Hooks-Overview
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there are no styling hooks for that label, you could just hide it via `variant="label-hidden"` and add your own label tag before the lightning-checkbox-group:

```html
<div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12 slds-var-p-top_xx-small">
    <label>Welke artikelen?</label>
    <lightning-checkbox-group
        name="newusedcheckboxgroup"
        label="Welke artikelen?"
        options={newUsedOptions}
        value={newUsedChoices}
        variant="label-hidden">
    </lightning-checkbox-group>
</div>
```

Then a bit of css to make it look like a standard slds label

```css
label {
    color: rgb(62, 62, 60);
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.125rem;
}
```

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/hxtUQKGWIZlj9paVqcui/src/app.html?p=stories)

Comment: Shame that it has to be done using a CSS hack, but it does the trick. Thank you!